# Why do I receive ENOTSUP error message? How can I fix it?

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I am trying to add packages in JuliaPro. For example I do this:
using Pkg
Pkg.add(“DataFrames”)
and the following error message pops up:
ERROR: IOError: mkdir: operation not supported on socket (ENOTSUP)

My OS is MacOS Big SUR 11.2.2. I also tried this using Julia (NOT Pro) and the same message pops up. I suspect this is something that might pop in various coding languages.

Could someone explain to me what is going on?
Many thanks!

Comment: It would be very helpful to get the complete error message and stack trace.